# Should I use paired t-tests or ANOVA when comparing multiple variables from 2 tests?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, t-test, reliability

I had 50 subjects perform two 30-minute cycling time trials on separate days. I would like to compare the means of several variables from each of the two tests: Cadence, Heart Rate, Power Output, and Perceived Exertion. I do not want to compare each variable to another (for example Cadence to Heart Rate), just to the same variable on the paired test (Cadence to Cadence, HR to HR etc). I am looking to report the day to day reliability of the 30-minute cycling test.

Should I use paired t-tests for each variable or run an ANOVA?

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple variables, the usual approach would be a multivariate test; this in effect identifies a linear combination of the variables that's most different.

If you want all the variables compared individually you could do paired tests, yes, or you could equivalently treat them as repeated measures ANOVA.

However, you should say something about what these measures consist of; are any counts? Are they typically skewed?

However, a t-test doesn't really tell you *how reliable* something is - failure to reject might indicate you don't have power.

If you define what you mean by reliability in this context, you'll probably find some other tool than hypothesis tests deals with that question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have values for the same 50 subjects on 2 different days, you essentially have *paired* data. So you should do a pairwise t-test.